# Total order on the subgroups of (Q,+)

Tags: group-theory, analysis

The problem im trying to solve is the following one :" Given G a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$,we choose $a\in G \backslash \{ 0 \}$. Prove that there exists an order "$>_{1}$" on G such that $a>0$ and G is a totally ordered group."
Here is my attempt:

I defined the order "$<_{1}$" by: $x<_{1}y$ if and only if $abs(x) < abs(y)$ where $abs$ corresponds to the absolute value. Then what i tried to do was to assume that there exists another order on G verifying what we stated earlier but thats where i got stuck. I tried several things such as assuming that there exists an $x$ for this second order such that $x \ne -x$ (which implies that this order is different from the first one) but all of them leads to nothing. Could you please give me some clues for the problem (i'd like to solve it by myself).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your $<_1$ is not working. Rather, if $a>0$, choose $<_1$ to be the same as $<$, while if $a<0$, then ...

Comment: I do not understand why it does not work. Isnt it reflexive, transitive and anti-symetric?

Comment: Since you seem to be dealing with strict order $<$ (and not $\le$), it should rather be *irreflexive*. Nevertheless, indeed it's a total ordering, however doesn't behave nicely with the group operation: e.g. you have $2<_1-3$ while $5=2+3\,\not<_1\,-3+3=0$.

Comment: Oh yes i didnt see that. I apologize im quite a new learner ^^'. Thank you :).

Comment: Im back! I used your definition of $<_{1}$ but i wonder how i can prove the unicity of an order such that a>0 and G is a totally ordered group. What comes to my mind first is either doing double inclusion or using argument to absurdity (assuming that there exists x such that $x>_{1} a$ and $x<_{2}a$ where $<_{2}$ is the second order) but none of those seems to work. Do you have any advices for this kind of problem?

Comment: Where is it written that such an order must be unique? As for the current wording of the problem, it only requires proving existence of such.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to precise that it has to be unique.

Comment: Nevertheless, have you figured out what order to take if $a<0$?

Comment: Yes, we take the order $<_{1}$ defined by $x<_{1} y$ if and only if $x>y$ where $>$ is the usual order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion doesn't work as it doesn't respect the additive group structure.

On the other hand, the usual ordering $<$ works, whenever $a>0$, and its opposite ($<_1\,:=\,>$) works for the case $a<0$.

To see this is the only such ordering, assumed $a>0$ generates an ordering $<_1$, let also $b\in G$ with $b>0$ be given, and write $b/a=\frac mn$ for positive integers $m,n$, so that $n\cdot b=m\cdot a$.

Since $a>_10$, we get $a+a>_1a+0=a>_10$ and so on, $m\cdot a>_1 0$.
By the same argument, if $b<_1 0$ was the case, we'd have $n\cdot b<_1 0$, which would be a contradiction.

This proves $b>0\implies b>_1 0$, and if $b<0$, then $-b>0$, hence $-b>_10$, and adding $b$ to both sides: $0>_1b$.

Comment: Thank you so much :).